# Why cannot append row to dataframe within panel object?

Tags: python, dataframe, append, panel

If I copy a dataframe which is an element of a panel, I can update it successfully using the append method. However, I cannot successfully update the dataframe that is the element of the panel. How can I update the dataframe that is the element of the panel?

Here is successful append on copy.

```
In [204]: pdata
Out[204]: 
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 696 (items) x 1 (major_axis) x 6 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 01-Apr-2014 to 31-Oct-2014
Major_axis axis: 0 to 0
Minor_axis axis: Date to Start Price

In [198]: test = pdata['20-Aug-2014']

In [199]: test
Out[199]: 
          Date Deal End Price Security Start Position Start Price
0  20-Aug-2014   PE        25    CU FP              3        17.4


In [200]: port.ix[233]
Out[200]: 
Date              20-Aug-2014
Security                CU FP
Deal                       PE
Start Price              17.4
Start Position              3
End Price                  25
Name: 233, dtype: object


In [201]: test.append(port.ix[233], ignore_index=True)
Out[201]: 
          Date Deal End Price Security Start Position Start Price
0  20-Aug-2014   PE        25    CU FP              3        17.4
1  20-Aug-2014   PE        25    CU FP              3        17.4

In [202]: test = test.append(port.ix[233], ignore_index=True)

In [203]: test
Out[203]: 
          Date Deal End Price Security Start Position Start Price
0  20-Aug-2014   PE        25    CU FP              3        17.4
1  20-Aug-2014   PE        25    CU FP              3        17.4
```

Here I try the same thing on the element of the panel, but it doesn't work:

```
In [204]: pdata
Out[204]: 
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 696 (items) x 1 (major_axis) x 6 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 01-Apr-2014 to 31-Oct-2014
Major_axis axis: 0 to 0
Minor_axis axis: Date to Start Price

In [206]: pdata['20-Aug-2014'] = pdata['20-Aug-2014'].append(port.ix[233], ignore_index=True)

In [207]: pdata['20-Aug-2014']
Out[207]: 
          Date Deal End Price Security Start Position Start Price
0  20-Aug-2014   PE        25    CU FP              3        17.4
```

Here I try to assign the modified copy of the data frame to the element in the panel and this also doesn't work:

```
In [208]: pdata['20-Aug-2014'] = test

In [209]: pdata['20-Aug-2014']
Out[209]: 
          Date Deal End Price Security Start Position Start Price
0  20-Aug-2014   PE        25    CU FP              3        17.4
```

How can I update the dataframe which is the element of the panel?

Thanks,

Gato

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best answer so I am interested if others have better approach, but I found I could drop the element, make a new panel with just the one entry and then concat the two panels. Seems like long way around to update a value, but it works.

```
In [204]: pdata
Out[204]: 
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 696 (items) x 1 (major_axis) x 6 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 01-Apr-2014 to 31-Oct-2014
Major_axis axis: 0 to 0
Minor_axis axis: Date to Start Price
In [209]: pdata['20-Aug-2014']
Out[209]: 
          Date Deal End Price Security Start Position Start Price
0  20-Aug-2014   PE        25    CU FP              3        17.4

In [211]: pdatatmp = pdata.drop('20-Aug-2014')

In [212]: pdatatmp
Out[212]: 
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 695 (items) x 1 (major_axis) x 6 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 01-Apr-2014 to 31-Oct-2014
Major_axis axis: 0 to 0
Minor_axis axis: Date to Start Price

In [215]: pdataupd = pd.Panel({'20-Aug-2014': test})

In [220]: pdata = pd.concat([pdatatmp, pdataupd])

In [222]: pdata
Out[222]: 
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 696 (items) x 2 (major_axis) x 6 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 01-Apr-2014 to 20-Aug-2014
Major_axis axis: 0 to 1
Minor_axis axis: Date to Start Price

In [223]: pdata['20-Aug-2014']
Out[223]: 
          Date Deal End Price Security Start Position Start Price
0  20-Aug-2014   PE        25    CU FP              3        17.4
1  20-Aug-2014   PE        25    CU FP              3        17.4

In [224]:
```

Comment: Turns out this is very inefficient, runs forever on even a few thousand updates, so I am interested if anyone has a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

First answer works, but not quite as expected. The element is updated, but I have found that panel expects all of its component dataframes to be of same dimension, so using the method concat in answer [0] inserts empty records in all the other element dataframes.

If we simply dispense with the panel construct and use a dict of dataframes, then we have the flexibility we require and the update works efficiently.

```
In [98]: pdata = {k: pstub for k in pdates['Dates'].values}

In [106]: port.ix[7]
Out[106]: 
Date              10-Jan-2014
Security              LIFE US
Deal                   TMO US
Start Price              75.8
Start Position            7.5
End Price                76.1
Name: 7, dtype: object

In [107]: pdata['10-Jan-2014'] = pdata['10-Jan-2014'].append(port.ix[7], ignore_index=True)

In [108]: pdata['09-Jan-2014']
Out[108]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Date, Deal, End Price, Security, Start Position, Start Price]
Index: []

In [109]: pdata['10-Jan-2014']
Out[109]: 
          Date    Deal  End Price Security  Start Position  Start Price
0  10-Jan-2014  TMO US       76.1  LIFE US             7.5         75.8

In [110]:
```